# Why are applications slowing down on the computer's second monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, display

Here's an interesting one.

### Problem

I have a user on Windows XP who is running a web application inside IE8. She has two monitors plugged in via  DVI cables.

When she is working the the browser on her primary monitor, everything is fine, but when she drags the window over to the second monitor, the web applications functionality grinds to a halt.

It's not just web apps either - many applications exhibit the problem.

### What I've tried

- Switching the two monitors in the OS. It's obviously not the monitor's fault.
- Confirmed that it's the app slowing down, and not the graphical rendering. The application in question actually locks up. The mouse is unaffected, and I can drag other windows on top of the problematic application.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about the video card? Driver is up to date ? (Other things I can think of is the CPU.. but I guess its not on 100% that time..right?)

Comment: what happens when you run that web app in the secondary then move it to the primary?

Answer (score 1):

It might still be the graphical rendering.

Does the problem go away if the application resides wholly on the secondary monitor?

A lot of graphics cards, particularity older ones perform *very* badly if an application spans multiple monitors. They work fine if the application is contained wholly within one screen or the other. We used to notice this particularly with 3d applications, but it can be any.

Comment: I agree with Chris; this is somehow related to the video card. Are you using a single card with dual outputs or two separate cards?